# ¿Añadir una imagen a "Controla tu musica tus videos y muchos mas"?

Tags: html, css

Al reproducir un audio en el navegador, aparece el icono de la imagen. Si se pulsa en él, en algunas páginas aparece una imagen, normalmente la del álbum de la canción, pero si se inserta tal como el código más adelante y se pulsa el icono no aparece ninguna imagen, solo la url de la web. Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo añadir una imagen? ¿Con CSS?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<audio controls src="song.mp4"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estoy aprendiendo a usar esto junto contigo así que espero ayudarte un poquito al menos.

Esta función se llama `Global Media Controls` en Chrome. Para personalizarlo deberemos hacer uso de html y javascript.

Como ya tienes el reproductor en el html, solo te faltaría modificar el [MediaSession](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSession) en `javascript`, qué básicamente es una API que gestiona el comportamiento de los contenidos multimedia.

```js
var sound = document.getElementById("myPlayer")

if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
    navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
        title: "TITLE",
        artist: "ARTIST",
        album: "ALBUM",
        artwork: [{
            sizes: "320x180",// Es necesario que tenga este tamaño estrictamente
            src: "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inficons/512/stackoverflow.png",
            type: ""
        }]
    });

    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function () {sound.play();});
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function () {sound.pause();});
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', function () {});
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', function () { });
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function () { });
    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', function () { });
}
```

```html
<audio id='myPlayer' controls>
  <source src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/1456.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Y con esto, podrás modificar el media controls del chrome, y personalizar los controles que quieres que se muestren.

Para ver el funcionamiento, ejecuta el snippet haz clic en los controles de audio del chrome y verás que se ha personalizado.

Answer (score 0):

La API de `mediaSession` te permite personalizar las notificaciones multimedia al proporcionar información de metadatos para los medios que reproduce tu aplicación web.

Este código javascript selecciona los `artwork` que aparecerán en el Global Media Controls. Aquí te dejo un [ejemplo de uso](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media-session/audio.html) donde podrás descargar el código fuente directamente para tu funcionamiento. También dejo enlace a [Github.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/media-session)

```
let audio = document.createElement('audio');

let playlist = getAwesomePlaylist();
let index = 0;

function onPlayButtonClick() {
  playAudio();
}

function playAudio() {
  audio.src = playlist[index].src;
  audio.play()
  .then(_ => updateMetadata())
  .catch(error => log(error));
}

function updateMetadata() {
  let track = playlist[index];

  log('Playing ' + track.title + ' track...');
  navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
    title: track.title,
    artist: track.artist,
    album: track.album,
    artwork: track.artwork
  });

  // Media is loaded, set the duration.
  updatePositionState();
}

/* Position state (supported since Chrome 81) */

function updatePositionState() {
  if ('setPositionState' in navigator.mediaSession) {
    log('Updating position state...');
    navigator.mediaSession.setPositionState({
      duration: audio.duration,
      playbackRate: audio.playbackRate,
      position: audio.currentTime
    });
  }
}

/* Previous Track & Next Track */

navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() {
  log('> User clicked "Previous Track" icon.');
  index = (index - 1 + playlist.length) % playlist.length;
  playAudio();
});

navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', function() {
  log('> User clicked "Next Track" icon.');
  index = (index + 1) % playlist.length;
  playAudio();
});

audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  // Play automatically the next track when audio ends.
  index = (index - 1 + playlist.length) % playlist.length;
  playAudio();
});

/* Seek Backward & Seek Forward */

let defaultSkipTime = 10; /* Time to skip in seconds by default */

navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', function(event) {
  log('> User clicked "Seek Backward" icon.');
  const skipTime = event.seekOffset || defaultSkipTime;
  audio.currentTime = Math.max(audio.currentTime - skipTime, 0);
  updatePositionState();
});

navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', function(event) {
  log('> User clicked "Seek Forward" icon.');
  const skipTime = event.seekOffset || defaultSkipTime;
  audio.currentTime = Math.min(audio.currentTime + skipTime, audio.duration);
  updatePositionState();
});

/* Play & Pause */

navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', async function() {
  log('> User clicked "Play" icon.');
  await audio.play();
  navigator.mediaSession.playbackState = "playing";
  // Do something more than just playing audio...
});

navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function() {
  log('> User clicked "Pause" icon.');
  audio.pause();
  navigator.mediaSession.playbackState = "paused";
  // Do something more than just pausing audio...
});

/* Stop (supported since Chrome 77) */

try {
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('stop', function() {
    log('> User clicked "Stop" icon.');
    // TODO: Clear UI playback...
  });
} catch(error) {
  log('Warning! The "stop" media session action is not supported.');
}

/* Seek To (supported since Chrome 78) */

try {
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekto', function(event) {
    log('> User clicked "Seek To" icon.');
    if (event.fastSeek && ('fastSeek' in audio)) {
      audio.fastSeek(event.seekTime);
      return;
    }
    audio.currentTime = event.seekTime;
    updatePositionState();
  });
} catch(error) {
  log('Warning! The "seekto" media session action is not supported.');
}

/* Utils */

function getAwesomePlaylist() {
  const BASE_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/media-session/';

  return [{
      src: BASE_URL + 'sintel/snow-fight.mp3',
      title: 'Snow Fight',
      artist: 'Jan Morgenstern',
      album: 'Sintel',
      artwork: [
        { src: BASE_URL + 'sintel/artwork-96.png',  sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'sintel/artwork-128.png', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'sintel/artwork-192.png', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'sintel/artwork-256.png', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'sintel/artwork-384.png', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'sintel/artwork-512.png', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
      ]
    }, {
      src: BASE_URL + 'big-buck-bunny/prelude.mp3',
      title: 'Prelude',
      artist: 'Jan Morgenstern',
      album: 'Big Buck Bunny',
      artwork: [
        { src: BASE_URL + 'big-buck-bunny/artwork-96.png',  sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'big-buck-bunny/artwork-128.png', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'big-buck-bunny/artwork-192.png', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'big-buck-bunny/artwork-256.png', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'big-buck-bunny/artwork-384.png', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'big-buck-bunny/artwork-512.png', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
      ]
    }, {
      src: BASE_URL + 'elephants-dream/the-wires.mp3',
      title: 'The Wires',
      artist: 'Jan Morgenstern',
      album: 'Elephants Dream',
      artwork: [
        { src: BASE_URL + 'elephants-dream/artwork-96.png',  sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'elephants-dream/artwork-128.png', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'elephants-dream/artwork-192.png', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'elephants-dream/artwork-256.png', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'elephants-dream/artwork-384.png', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'elephants-dream/artwork-512.png', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
      ]
    }, {
      src: BASE_URL + 'caminandes/original-score.mp3',
      title: 'Original Score',
      artist: 'Jan Morgenstern',
      album: 'Caminandes 2: Gran Dillama',
      artwork: [
        { src: BASE_URL + 'caminandes/artwork-96.png',  sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'caminandes/artwork-128.png', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'caminandes/artwork-192.png', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'caminandes/artwork-256.png', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'caminandes/artwork-384.png', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
        { src: BASE_URL + 'caminandes/artwork-512.png', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
      ]
    }];
}
```

Comment: El ejemplo ayudaría más aquí y el enlace solo como referencia

Comment: no he puesto el ejemplo porque tiene muchas líneas de código. Cuando se entra al ejemplo de uso está el código para copiar.

Comment: Ya lo revise y en realidad es poco y si queda, te lo digo por que si el enlace caduca entonces tu respuesta pierde sentido

Comment: ok, lo pongo entonces